# Code Igniter loading views vs loading JS files

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

Is one superior to the other and if so which? My co-worker says that we need to load JS files rather than views with JS inside them due to browser caching. But when I look at the runtime for loading a view, it looks negligible. I see lots of advantages to loading views and the only rebuttal my coworker could make was browser caching. What’s the right answer here?

E.G. which is superior or are they the same?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/file.js"></script>
```

OR

```
$this->load->view(“views/path/to/file”);
```

The view version is a php file not a js file. Thanks!!

Comment: don't trust your dev box to report real-world conditions. What's negligible to a decent desktop box on fast internet might not be negligible to a phone over 3G... You also need to consider the server load, bandwidth, and wasted bandwidth each approach causes, not just raw speed. It's concerning that you consider the only "rebuttal" to be correctly setting up your webserver, which for most pros is a given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For purposes of code reuse, I think embedding views inside other views is best whenever the embedded views need to share view variables.

This way multiple views can share the same sub-view and that sub-view still has direct access to those variables.

Javascript files won't work for this purpose because Javascript files cannot have view variables inside of them.

However, when the Javascript does not use any view variables, then it may be better to use them.

Usually the Javascript has view variables in it though so I usually do the former.

Loading these views takes a millisecond each but it's well worth the benefit of sharing code. Otherwise I'd wouldn't have a single edit point and you can't put view variables inside of JS files.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the natural javascript implementation is probably better in terms of time taken simply because this is what's going to happen anyway (in the second version PHP simply renders before the browser gets  the file).

Your co-worker is right about caching as well, this is what browsers are designed to do, reload a file only when it believes it to be necessary.

Having said that you do need to think about how much that slight performance advantage is going to benefit the application. If you have 10 users and `$this->load` is better for development, do that. If you have 3 million users or `$this->load` doesn't really help you all that much, use the natural js implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely loading the js standalone is better as it will save the time for whole loading process and the file and after load the fill it will not pass to php engine to process the file and then let the php ignore the part of file that is not php, your case most of the file will be ignore.

If you have problem with caching you can set the header on your index file to tell the browser not to cache the page.

```
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);`
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```